# Can I use Google's public DNS numeric ID for my nameservers?

Tags: domain-name-system

Recently I have got a nameservers update problem. But two weeks have passed and the new nameservers are still not updated at most of my local ISPs. It seems those updates are manual.

There must be a better way!!!

Indeed, Google public DNS servers updated almost immediatelly.

But can I go to my server, open the cpanel advanced DNS settings screen, 
and use the numeric IP of the Google's public nameservers,
instead of the nameservers of my hosting company? 
Or am I missing something basic here?

Comment: What update are you waiting for? (What did you change?)

Comment: You're proposing a solution without showing us the problem.  Specifically, your first two sentences should be replaced with some actual examples of what you're seeing instead of generic terms like 'update' and 'problem'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that won't work.

When you tell the internet, please use `8.8.8.8` as my nameservers, everyone will ask that IP  where it should go to find `example.com`. The problem is, `8.8.8.8` *doesn't actually know*, it will (normally) ask your real nameservers, then cache that result and return it to anyone that asks.

If you set your nameservers to point to Google, your domains will stop resolving entirely, because no-one is available to say where it goes. Your real nameservers stop this loop, by saying "yes, I own this domain, so I'll tell you where you should go" rather than "nope, I don't know, but let me find out for you and I'll get back to you momentarily".